# Expo Jest can't find images like 'file@2x.png'

Tags: image, request, automated-tests, jestjs, expo

As you know, Expo uses adaptive images size by analyzing the suffix of the file like the following:
`xxx@3x.png`
`xxx@2x.png`
`xxx@1x.png`

I can declare the images omitting the end of the file like that:

```
const iconHomeButton = require('./images/homeButton.png');
```

The real image name actually, on the folder, is:

`homeButton@2x.png`

On Expo it works fine but when I try to test it using Jest it can't find the image. 
If I change the name of the file to the real name like:

```
const iconHomeButton = require('./images/homeButton@2x.png');
```

then the Jest Test works.

Is there any way to test it using Jest without change my Expo project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Configuring the Jest in `package.json` can solve the problem. Adding the `moduleNameMapper` will turn your test fine:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^[@./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\\.(png|jpg|gif)$": "RelativeImageStub"
      }
}
```